# ES6 Map Returning Null in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a JSON file which provides the value to Gatsby and Gatsby through the gatsby-source-filesystem reads that file. I am using GraphQL with `gatsby-transformer-json` which gives me the query like below to access all the values of JSON in the code

```
    {
      allSrcJson {
       totalCount
       edges {
         node {
          total
          results {
            account
          }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Now in my code when I am trying to do a .map, it works on the first time whereas next time it says `Cannot read property 'account' of undefined` whereas when I write node.results[0].account it gives me the result.

```
{data.allSrcJson.edges.map(({ node }) => (
   <div key={node.total}>
     <p>{node.total}</p>
     {node.results.map(({ result }) => (
       <p>{result.account}</p>
     ))};
   </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to diagnose this without seeing the data, but it sounds like there is at least member of your `results` array that does not have a `result` property on it.  If you try taking out the second object destructuring, and log out the object, you'll see which one is failing.  (Or maybe you meant to do the second object destructuring like this `node.results.map({ account })`)

```
{node.results.map(obj => {
    console.log(obj)
    if (obj.result) {
        return <p>{obj.result.account}</p>
    } else return null
})
```

Comment: I guess I have figured out the problem, I was not returning the value like `return <p>{result.account}</p>`, that did the trick. Thanks